# Google sign-in fail: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included

Tags: android, google-play-services

A project was working just fine. Some users started to complain about this issue (could not sign in to Google).

To verify it's a device issue and not application issue I've tested sign-in to Google with different app (it failed too):
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.aifactory.chessfree&hl=en

Thus far I think those are the common facts in all cases:

- Started early June 2017. See more recent reports at the comments to the top answer here: [LogCat message: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068627/logcat-message-the-google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-check-your-pr)
- Android 6.0 devices
- Maybe: Google Play Services 11.0.55 (436-156917137)

Devices:

- Samusng Galaxy S5
- Nexus 7 (2013)

Any work around this time or we just have to wait for Google Play Services update?

Answer (score 1):

You may try other workarounds found in these threads:

- [The Google Play services resources were not Found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793998/the-google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-error)

  > Go to android-sdk folder in your system then extras->google->google_play_services->libproject-> google-play-services_lib
  >
  > Import google-play-services_lib in your workspace and then add this library project to your own project. Your issue will be hopefully resolved.
- [Using Ads gets me a "Resources were not found"](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/19)

  > The message in that case must just be a check I suppose. The resources not found message is referring to the library resources, which are included in it, not to some resources on the phone.

Hope this helps.